# need auto populate the fields while select the contact from filter in suitecrm

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I created one module called Participants with Contact filters, Office Phone and email.

My Question is if i select a Contact from filter remaining fields should populate with contact person data.

Please see the attached screen shot.

here i selected one contact from the filter that contact person Office Phone and email should fill automatically.

[image]

Regards,
kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this link: https://suitecrm.com/community/developer-help/5407-auto-populate-contact-phone-number-when-user-is-selected

This may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply..its helped me a lot and based on this post i can populate all the fields which i want except email.Do you have any idea how do i populate email?.

Comment: Because email is an additional related field, you need to populate two fields. The first being the email address field and the second being a hidden id field. You will need to view the source in the browser and find the hidden field below your email address. It might be something like Participants0emailAddress0Id.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there are many way to do that in sugarcrm ,

1. You can use calculated field do populate fields .
2. You use API in your js file and and according to filter you can populate data.

Try some google you will find many answers already given.

Comment: try to use calculated field

Comment: How can i use calculated fields? can you give me some examples.